# if present then delete from array of string else insert it (mongoose schema)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

this is my mongoose schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    solved: [{type: String}]
})
```

the thing i want to do is if my **query** is present in the *solved* array of string then i would like to delete it from the *solved* array and if the **query** does not exist in the *solved* array then i would like to push the **query** into *solved* array

i tried it by using findOneAndUpdate but it didn't work the way i wanted.

any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single query, you can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$cond` to check if the string is in `solved` array
- if it's in array then filter the document and remove the matching string using `$filter`
- else concat current `solved` array with new string using `$concatArrays`

```
let str = "a";
await UserModel.updateMany( // updateOne
  {}, // your query
  [{
    $set: {
      solved: {
        $cond: [
          { $in: [str, "$solved"] },
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$solved",
              cond: { $ne: ["$$this", str] }
            }
          },
          { $concatArrays: ["$solved", [str]] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XXPFui7A4U5)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the $in operator that find the object that have the query in the array (if there is one), and later update it using classic update

Comment: okay will try it btw will $in return some value by which i can know if the element is present or not?

Comment: bro it is updating but how to delete?

Comment: manually update your array using loadash or similar, then update it and save;

Comment: example doc.a = modifiedA, doc.save()